# Trouble when creating a paint calculator

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Heys guys, completely beginner coder here. I am trying to create a paint calculator in HTML and Java. I'm fairly sure it is all wrong so I'm sorry about that in advance. Nothing works at the moment, I don't know why, but it could be a simple fix or a deeper problem with the way I am trying to code.

Basically I am trying to multiply the wallLength and the wallHeight to get the wallArea, add that to the type of paint the user selects, and add an undercoat if they select it. Then I want the result to be displayed under all the other input boxes.

`

```
    <div id="walls">
        <legend>Calculate the area of your walls!</legend>
            <label>Input the length and height of your walls.<br><br></label>
                <input type="text" id="wallHeight" value="Height of walls" onchange="calculateTotal()"> Height of the walls. <br> (Must be between 2 and 6 metres).<br> <br>
                <input type="text" id="wallLength" value="Length of walls" onchange="calculateTotal()"> Length of the walls. <br>(Walls must be between 1 and 25 metres).<br> <br>
                <input type="text" id="wallNumber" value="Number of walls" onchange="calculateTotal()">Number of walls.             
    </div>  

        <div id="painttype">    
            <label>Paint Type <br><br> </label>
                <input type="radio" id="luxuryPaint" name="selectedPaint" value="luxury" onchange="calculateTotal()">Luxury Quality (&#163;1.75 per square metre)<br>
                <input type="radio" id="standardPaint" name="selectedPaint" value="standard" onchange="calculateTotal()">Standard Quality (&#163;1.00 per square metre) <br>
                <input type="radio" id="economyPaint" name="selectedPaint" value="economy" onchange="calculateTotal()">Economy Quality (&#163;0.45 per square metre) <br>
            <p>
                <label for='underCoat' class="inlinelabel">Do you want an undercoat?</label> <br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="underCoat" value="undercoat" onchange="calculateTotal()"/>Undercoat (&#163;0.50 per square metre extra)                          
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="result">
            <p>
            <input type="text" id="wallResult" value="Area of walls">
            <input type="text" id="resultBox" value="Result">
            </p>
```

`

Sorry, I don't know how to add the Javascript code without its format screwing up, but the javascript is in the fiddle link, sorry about that.

[Here's the fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/d3dL6boL/1/)

I am grateful for any help you give me.
Thanks

Edited:Added JS to fiddle.

Comment: Hi Will, your fiddle doesnt appear to contain any javascript code, can you please edit it?

Comment: @Ben Sorry, I could've sworn I added the JS, but its there now. Or here: https://jsfiddle.net/d3dL6boL/1/.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here, the biggest being that you never actually call your calculateWalls paintType or underCoat functions anywhere, meaning the code inside of them is never run.

Also, there is no html object with ID paintResult, so this line
var paintResult=document.getElementById("paintResult");
is never going to behave properly, similarly this line
var undercoatResult=document.getElementById("underCoat"); should be replaced with using the undercoat var, which needs to be defined outside of the underCoat function to be used. 
lastly 
var wallResult=document.getElementById("wallResult");

should be
var wallResult=document.getElementById("wallResult").value;

Those changes should hopefully be enough to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The only function ever called is `calculateTotal()` and the variables inside `calculateTotal()` aren't set so it will always fail.

I would expect to see something like this, just a warning this is more psuedo code, the syntax may not be correct:

```
<input type="text" id="wallHeight" value="Height of walls" onchange="calculateWalls()">
```

and then the `calculateWalls()` function does the work:

```
if(wallHeight > 0 && wallLength > 0){
    //DO WALL CALCULATION

    //PASS RESULT TO CACLULATETOTAL
    calculateTotal(wallResult);
}
```